# Using Indy components to verify Smart Card credential

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, indy10, c++builder-10-seattle

Does Indy components have any kink of functionality to verify the credential of a Smart Card (CAC)? I am assuming it has to be used in conjunction with `InitializeSecurityContext`.

I am using it in C++ Builder Seattle but even Delphi examples would be appreciated.

Here is what I have figured out so far:

1. Open System Certificate Store (`CertOpenSystemStore`) and let the
   user select a certificate (`CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore`).
2. Get the Credential Handle (`AcquireCredentialsHandle`).
3. Connect to my server using `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` using the secure port 443.
4. call `InitializeSecurityContext` which returns ***SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED***.

After that I am not sure what should be sent to server and what to expect in return. Also at which point the system should ask the user for the PIN?

Thank you

Comment: Indy components do NOT have smart card or payment terminal (POS) stuff. You have to write it yourself.  You have not identified the payment terminal type, but even if you did, I can tell you, nobody here is going to write a giant slab of POS payment system code for you.    The Concern of INDY is to provide components for basic IETF RFC protocols, things like HTTP, FTP, and so on.  What you're talking about is called an APPLICATION LAYER concern. The stuff that goes back and forth via HTTP and HTTPS is not Indy's problem, it's YOURS.

Comment: This is not about any kind of payment. Military uses something called "Common Access Card" (AKA CAC) for identification/verification. The card contains a bunch of Certificates for different purposes, The idea is multi step verification. In this case the user has to have something unique (The card) and know something (The pin for accessing the Certificates on the card). I am writing an app that needs to authenticate the user by using the certificate on the smart card. I also know about Indy's role. As I said above, I'm already connecting to the server. I don't know what to sent and receive.

Comment: This is still a very small vertical market Application concern. Indy doesn't handle the problem "I don't know how to send bytes to my server". You do.

Answer (score 1):

When you get `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED`, you are supposed to transfer the output token data to the server, wait for a response token, and then pass that back to `InitializeSecurityContext()`.  Now, how you actually transfer the data back and forth depends on the particular protocol you are using to communicate with the server.

For example, in `TIdHTTP`, Indy has a `TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication` class for handling NTLM authentication using the same API you are using.  It initializes the NTML security package and then uses `InitializeSecurityContext()` to retrieve a buffer of bytes containing NTLM token data, which is then base64 encoded put into an HTTP `Authorization: NTML ...` request header.  When the response comes back, if it has an HTTP `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM ...` header offering the response token data, the data is base64 decoded and the resulting bytes are fed back into `InitializeSecurityContext()`.

So, you need to figure out what communication protocol you are using to talk to your server, and how that protocol expects you to transmit the token bytes back and forth.  That is outside of Indy's scope.  It provides you with the means of transmitting and receiving bytes, but you have to supply and read them as needed.